# The Hunger Games: Original books vs. Movie Tie-in Edition

Tags: the-hunger-games

I was thinking about jumping into Hunger Games universe, thanks to @randal'thor, but when I searched Kindle Store, I also found Movie Tie-in Editions of each books. I am now confused.

What are the differences between original books and Movie Tie-in Editions of *The Hunger Games*? Which one should I read provided that I don't know anything about The Hunger Games except it's a bestseller beaten only by Harry Potter? Are Movie Tie-in Editions intended for those audiences who have already watched movies without reading the books? Can I enjoy reading both editions?

**Note:** Please, don't spoil me. Strictly, I don't want to know any in-universe thing.

Comment: Is the actual book different or just the cover?

Comment: On a side note. I would recco you to watch movies only. They are more than sufficient. The book, although good, is writen as first person POV & hence little frustrating

Comment: @KharoBangdo - sorry I disagree. The books were much better than the films. Not that they were great books, but still.

Comment: @KharoBangdo I disagree. The films are very good, but (as always) the books give you much more background detail and enable you to understand a lot that you can't get just from the films. True, they're first-person PoV, but being able to see inside Katniss's head tells you a lot more than you can learn by just watching people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Movie tie-in editions generally just have different covers and marketing -- the contents are exactly the same. So it shouldn't matter which edition you read, and there's certainly no point reading both of them. The [Amazon listing](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Hunger-Games-Tie-Edition-ebook/dp/B0071DJZZA) confirms that, saying:

> Here is the original novel with new movie artwork on the cover.

Comment: +1. Fun fact - I avoided reading Interview with a Vampire for years because I could only find it with a Keanu Reeves/Tom Cruise cover. Then I read it, and found a new reason to have avoided reading it.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Come now, that's got to be one of the best homo-erotic vampire books I've ever read.

Answer (score 3):

Most novels publish "movie tie-in" editions when they get adapted into films.

The cover will be different, and often there will be stills from the movie included in a centerfold. (Depending on how much the movie deviates from the source material, the included pictures may come across as pretty bizarre to one reading the book.)

The text, however, will remain unchanged.

Comment: "Depending on how much the movie deviates from the source material" - Hunger Games is one of the best book-to-film adaptations I've ever read/watched. So much so that I even feel comfortable imagining the book characters looking like their film actors!

Comment: This answer could be improved if you find some industry expert confirming that this is indeed the practice.